# How to compute the fiber of point between algebraic stacks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, fibre-product

Suppose $f: \mathcal{X}\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism from an algebraic stack $\mathcal{X}$ to a scheme $Y$. It can induce a unique topological morphism $|f|:\mathcal{|X|}\rightarrow Y$.

Suppose $y\in Y$ is a point of $Y$, my question is if $|f|^{-1}(y)\subseteq |\mathcal{X}|$ with the induced topology, homeomoephic to $|\mathcal{X}\times_Y k(y)|$?

Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I give a look-like proof for $Y=Spec \mathbb{Z}$. For arbitary scheme $Y$ the proof should be the same. I have to say show these stuff looks very sloppy.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should edit this answer to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users have an easier time finding this ^_^

Comment: I am willing to do this, but is this possible to edit it directly in Math stackexchange?

Comment: If you click the `edit` button at the bottom of your post, it will let you make the changes.